# when i include sub report into my main report its showing Resource not found at

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I made jasper report when I include sub report into my main report its showing
`net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Resource not found at :D:\Jasper_Report\Newfolder\AddressReport.jasper`

but AddressReport.jasper already there in my location.

```
<subreport>
            <reportElement positionType = "Float" x = "335" y = "25" width = "175" height = "20"/>
            <dataSourceExpression>
               new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource
                  ($F{subReportBeanList})
            </dataSourceExpression>
            <subreportExpression class = "java.lang.String">
               <![CDATA["D:\\Jasper_Report\\Newfolder\\AddressReport.jasper"]]>
            </subreportExpression>
         </subreport>
```

Comment: Are you using Jaspersoft Studio? Does this error appear in there? If so are you sure you haven't made a typo?

Comment: No i am using eclipse.Develop jrxml file in ireport designer tool.

Comment: I've tried this in Jaspersoft Studio and it works just fine. The only difference was "class = "java.lang.String"" - it got auto-removed. Anyway, your code should work as long as you haven't made a typo in path/filename (or it's a bug in ireport)